# Amazon S3 SdkClientException while Directory Uploading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

I am using this code for uploading directory on S3.

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3client);
MultipleFileUpload uploaded = transferManager.uploadDirectory(BUCKET_NAME, "DirectoryName", new File(uploadDirectory), true);
```

While uploading Directory to Amazon S3 bucket I get the following exception

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Upload canceled
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:159)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This exception generally occur around 10 times in 100 attempt

> Note- The above code is executing in Multithreaded environment with the same `s3client` object

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of s3Bucket you are using

Comment: please add cause of exception printed in stacktrace. It may fail because of number of hits exceed than the  limiting given :) I Hope I will suggest u to use above version 1.10 or later

Comment: @VikrantKashyap this is all i got in stacktrace. Where we can give limit because i have not given anywhere.

Comment: @RahulGupta 1.11.190

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solution of above problem i encountered while doing R&D in Java Amazon Sdk. Instead of creating different `TransferManager` instances for every thread share the same instances with multiple threads if you are using same `AmazonS3Client`.

It will not cause any issue because it is thread safe object and problem was also solved.

Comment: I've met the same issue, thanks for the R&D. Did you figure out why is an issue for multiple TransferManagers share the same AmazonS3Client?